# Problems after switching from MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2018 to MacBook Pro 16" Late 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, display, battery

Today I've got my new [MacBook Pro 16" Late 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809). It will replace my "old" [MacBook Pro 13" mid-2018](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP775).

I've set it up as a new MacBook and just copied over some files.

I now have a massive battery problem. It says "Battery not charging" all the time. It even losses Power. My setup worked well with my 13" Macbook. I've tried the article from the Apple Help Page, but that didn't work.

Also, I've connected my 2 [LG 32UK550-B](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-32UK550-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor) Monitors. They now have a really ugly tint to it. The Color Options also change in the Monitors menu depending on the connected MacBook. My 13" is just fine with like 20 Color Profiles and my 16" just has 4 profiles. All look ugly.

Can someone help me here? Do I have a faulty MacBook?

Comment: When you say "It even loses power," what percentage does the battery get down to? Will it eventually start charging again?

Comment: It is now at 26%. Since I just unboxed it today, it didnt got to 0 yet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you using the power supply and cable that is included with the new MacBook Pro? Which support article are you referring to, could you add the link? Are you connecting the monitors to the new MacBook Pro in the same manner (port/adapter) as you did with the old MacBook Pro?

Comment: Take it back to Apple. This. Should. Not. Be. Happening.

Comment: I can't up vote @SteveChambers comment enough.  If you unbox a brand new product (anything from any mfg.) and it utterly disappoints, take it back for refund/exchange!  There should be zero tolerance for this.

Comment: After reading the friendly manual of course. Getting great support is alway better than an exchange or repair. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turned out I really didn’t use the correct power supply. I used the one from my 13” MacBook and it turned out I need the full wattage charger.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

The Monitors also work now. Just had to turn off HDR in my MacBooks Display Settings.

Comment: Thank you for asking. It’s always worrisome when a new product disappoints us.